# How to connect multiple mongodb database dynamically using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my project there are many database, one is masterDb and all other are database connect based on the masterDb. For example , in the verification page the user can enter a 'company id', this 'company id' can be checked with the masterDb and if an id exist it then return the database name for the specific company. Using the database name i want to connect to the specific company database.

Now i can successfully login and i get the db name. Using this db name (req.headers['x-key-db']) i can connect to the specific database. but here i place the database connection code inside every api call. Is there any another way to create it once and use it in every api call dynamically.

```js
app.get('/api/student-limited/:_pageNumber/:_pageSize', function(req, res) {
  
 var db = mongoose.createConnection();
 db.open('mongodb://localhost:27017/'+req.headers['x-key-db']);
 var ClassSection = db.model('ClassSections', SectionSchema);
 var Student = db.model('Students', StudentSchema);
 
 var _pageNumber = parseInt(req.params._pageNumber), _pageSize = parseInt(req.params._pageSize);
 Student.find({}, function (err, _docs) {
  if(_docs){
   Student.find({}, null, {sort: { Name: 1} }).skip(_pageNumber > 0 ? ((_pageNumber-1)*_pageSize) : 0).limit(_pageSize).populate('_idClass').exec(function (err, docs) {
   if(err)
    res.json(err);
   else
    res.json({ "TotalCount" : _docs.length, "_Array" : docs});
       });
     }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create a module like below which will check if database connection for database you need already exists. If it does, it will return the connection object otherwise it will create one and return it.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Object holding all your connection strings
var connections = {};

exports.getDatabaseConnection = function(dbName) {

    if(connections[dbName]) {
        //database connection already exist. Return connection object
        return connections[dbName];
    } else {
        connections[dbName] = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/' + dbName);
        return connections[dbName];
    }       
}
```

Suppose you name above file as `data.js`. You just need to require this module in the file where you have your API code. And your API code will be changed to something like:

```
app.get('/api/student-limited/:_pageNumber/:_pageSize', function(req, res) {
    //Call getDatabaseConnection function we created
    var db = data.getDatabaseConnection(req.headers['x-key-db']);
    var ClassSection = db.model('ClassSections', SectionSchema);
    var Student = db.model('Students', StudentSchema);

    var _pageNumber = parseInt(req.params._pageNumber), _pageSize = parseInt(req.params._pageSize);
    Student.find({}, function (err, _docs) {
        if(_docs){
            Student.find({}, null, {sort: { Name: 1} }).skip(_pageNumber > 0 ? ((_pageNumber-1)*_pageSize) : 0).limit(_pageSize).populate('_idClass').exec(function (err, docs) {
            if(err)
                res.json(err);
            else
                res.json({ "TotalCount" : _docs.length, "_Array" : docs});
             });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The database connection works fine. :)

Comment: Looks like connections['dbName'] should be connections[dbName]

Comment: Hi, I tried but throws me error like getDatabaseConnection is not a function. Please suggest me

Comment: @Raeesaa Hi there. I'm curious to know if this solution would create race conditions if multiple users tried to call the getDatabaseConnection() function at the same time. I understand that it is possible that the variable that holds all the connection objects could be edited using a single thread but I'm not sure if this would necessarily be the case here, because connections to the database can be created asynchronously.

Comment: Hi @NikitasIO, I don't think there would be race condition as we are saving `mongoose.createConnection` to `connections` object and not its response / callback result. So even though `createConnection` itself is async, there won't be any race conditions. Having said that I had tested this code around 6-7 years back and in case there were any changes in mongoose APIs recently, things might not work as expected.